# Four balls are randomly dropped into four boxes

Tags: probability

Four balls are randomly dropped into four boxes, where any ball is equally likely to fall into
each box.

For a fixed $k = 0, 1, 2, 3$, let $A_k$ denote the event that exactly $k$ boxes are empty. Compute
$P(A_k)$ for each $k = 0, 1, 2, 3$.

I have computed $P(A_0)$ and $P(A_3)$ which are $\frac{4!}{4^4}=\frac{3}{32}$ and $\frac{4}{4^4}=\frac{1}{64}$ recpectively. But I don't know how to find $P(A_1)$ and $P(A_2)$. Could anybody help me?

Comment: Hint: for $P(A_1)$, how many choices for the sole empty box and the sole box with two balls in it? How many different options for the two balls in the box with two balls? for the two singleton boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine temporarily that each ball had its own color.  We see then that there are $4^4$ equally likely outcomes for where the balls are positioned.  We get as you already did the probabilities $P(A_0)=\dfrac{4!}{4^4}$ and $P(A_3)=\dfrac{4}{4^4}$

Now., for $P(A_1)$, count the numerator using the following multiplication principle argument:

- Pick which box was empty: $4$ choices
- Pick which box received two balls: $3$ choices
- Pick which two colored balls go into the box designated to receive two balls: $\binom{4}{2}$ choices
- Pick which colored ball goes into the left-most box designated to receive one ball: $2$ choices
- The final ball goes into the final box designated to receive one ball

This gives a total of $4\cdot 3\cdot \binom{4}{2}\cdot 2$ options here for a probability then of

$$P(A_1)=\dfrac{144}{4^4}$$

We can similarly calculate for the other case, taking advantage of the fact that the boxes are arranged from left to right, giving a total of $\binom{4}{2}\binom{4}{2} = 36$ if there were two boxes, each with two balls in them and $4\cdot 3\cdot 4=48$ if there was one box with three and another box with only one, for a total of $84$ outcomes and a probability of:

$$P(A_2)=\dfrac{84}{4^4}$$

Checking, $4!+144+84+4 = 256$ and so we do get our probabilities adding to one as expected.

Comment: thank you. I just don't understand the 4.3.4= 48 part. There are 4 boxes to which 3 balls would go and then 3 choices for the other one to go into. Then we multiply this by 4 because we can choose 4 ways to pick these 2 receiving boxes, am i right?

Comment: @ThePoorJew The first $4$ is deciding which box receives the three balls.  Next, the $3$ is in deciding which of the remaining boxes is the one to receive the one ball.  Finally, the remaining $4$ is in reference to picking which color goes into the box that gets one ball while the remaining balls will all go into the box that gets the rest.

Answer (score 0):

I'll write out the computation "by hand" for $A_2$. There are slicker answers, but this doesn't require any clever observations.

First we drop the first ball, and it doesn't matter where it goes. Then we drop the second ball. There is a $1/4$ chance it lands in the same place as the first, and a $3/4$ chance otherwise. So
$$
P(A_2) = \frac{1}{4} P(A_2 | \text{same}) + \frac{3}{4} P(A_2 | \text{different}).
$$
If they landed in different places, then we don't care where balls 3 and 4 land as long as they land in the boxes already occupied. The probability of this is $1/2$ for each, and the events are independent, so
$$
   P(A_2) = \frac{1}{4} P(A_2 | \text{same}) + \frac{3}{4} \cdot\frac{1}{2} \cdot\frac{1}{2}.
$$ 
If the first two balls landed in the same place, then drop the third ball. Either it lands in the first place again, with probability $1/4$, or lands in a second place. If it lands in a second place, then we just need the fourth ball to land in one of the two already occupied.
$$
   P(A_2) = \frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{1}{4} P(A_2| 3 \text{same}) + \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \right) + \frac{3}{4} \cdot\frac{1}{2} \cdot\frac{1}{2}.
$$ 
If the first three balls all landed in the same place, then we need the fourth ball to land somewhere else, with probability $3/4$. So we have
$$
 P(A_2) = \frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{1}{4} \cdot\frac{3}{4} + \frac{3}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \right) + \frac{3}{4} \cdot\frac{1}{2} \cdot\frac{1}{2} = \frac{3 + 6 + 12}{64} = \frac{21}{64}.
$$

Answer (score -1):

$P(A_0)=\frac{1}{35}$ because the only possibility is the every has exactly one ball.
$P(A_3)=\frac{4}{35}$ because there are 4 possibility to choose the one who isn't empty.
$P(A_1)=\frac{\binom{4}{1}\cdot3}{35}$ because the first binomial is the way to choose the one without the ball, and the way to give 4 balls to 3 people so that every of them has at least 1 ball.
$P(A_2)=\frac{\binom{4}{2}\cdot\binom{3}{2}}{35}$ because the first binomial is the way to choose the two without the ball, and the second binomial is the way to give 4 balls to 2 people so that every of them has at least 1 ball.

Comment: It should be obvious that $P(A_0)+P(A_1)+P(A_2)+P(A_3)=1$.  It follows then that if your proposed values of these do not add up to one then there must be some mistake.  Yours don't add up to $1$.

Comment: A hint on how to correct this... Imagine if you would that each ball were a different color.  Your calculations do not take the different colors into account.  In effect, your numerators were acting as though each outcome where color didn't matter were equally likely to occur when in reality they are not while your denominator treated color as important.

Comment: Sorry i failed to read I thought that the question was on the case with the balls all equally. Sorry again. (Before the denominator was a mistake.)

Comment: Oh, the balls are all identical in the way that I read the problem too.  That doesn't mean though that the different distinct arrangements are all equally likely to occur.  For instance, the outcome where each box gets one ball is far more likely to occur than the first box getting all the balls.  It is through convenience that we may imagine that the balls are colored.  Imagining the balls are colored does not change the final probabilities, though it does allow us to work in an equiprobable sample space, something we generally prefer to do, which allows us to use counting methods.

Comment: I see that you have since edited your answer and changed the denominator.  Your answer still doesn't add up to 1.  Also, I will reiterate... the outcomes you are basing your calculations on are not equally likely to occur!  You may only calculate probabilities as number of good outcomes divided by total number of outcomes if they are equally likely.  The outcomes where there isn't color to consider are not equally likely, making your attempt incorrect.  If you are unconvinced, compare this to the problem where we flip two coins and count the number of heads.